# python module for handling version of software

Tags: java, python, maven, continuous-integration, version

I am looking for a python module / library which will be to operate on 'software versions'... Which means, for example:

- compare versions "1.0-SNAPSHOT" and "1.1-SNAPSHOT" and tell which is newer
- increment "1.0.1-SNAPSHOT" to "1.0.2-SNAPSHOT"
- make "1.0" from "1.0-SNAPSHOT" and same with '-RELEASE'

Yes, versions naming comes in this came from java (maven) world - my python part should operate on them..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`distutils`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/) has some support for this.

```
>>> from distutils.version import LooseVersion  # or StrictVersion
>>> LooseVersion("1.0-SNAPSHOT") < LooseVersion("1.1-SNAPSHOT")
True
>>> v = LooseVersion("1.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
>>> v.version
[1, 0, 1, '-SNAPSHOT']
```

You'll have to do the incrementing and other manipulation yourself though.

Comment: can I make reverse operation? From [1, 0, 1, '-SNAPSHOT'] make "1.0.1-SNAPSHOT" ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You can only construct a `LooseVersion` from a string and updating its `version` member does not cause it to have a different `vstring`.

Answer (score 3):

the distutils/disutils2 package contain a module named version, which provides useful classes:

```
import distutils
>>> vs1 = distutils.version.LooseVersion("1.0-SNAPSHOT")
>>> vs2 = distutils.version.LooseVersion("1.1-SNAPSHOT")
>>> vs1 < vs2
True
```

Hope that helps!